# Como carregar um banco de dados da Oracle no R?

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, oracle

Eu tenho acesso a um banco de dados da Oracle, mas sempre utilizei esses dados no R utilizando o `PL/SQL` para extrair os dados em `csv`. Mas agora eu gostaria de conectar meu banco de dados da Oracle no próprio `RStudio`.

Depois de algumas pesquisas, encontrei algumas soluções, mas mesmo assim não consegui fazer que elas funcionem.

```
install.packages("RODBC")

library(RODBC)

Conectar_Oracle = odbcDriverConnect("driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};
                       server='123.456.7.89';
                       database='banco01';
                       uid='usuario';
                       pwd='senha'")
```

Mas veio a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado
```

Em alguns fóruns dizem que necessita instalação do conector da Oracle, em outros diz que é possível conectar com o banco diretamente. Mas não consegui fazer funcionar nenhuma dessas opções.

Podem me ajudar? Onde estou errando? O que eu devo fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mim o que funcionou foi usar o `RJDBC`.

O arranjo que estou propondo usa dois arquivos na pasta. Um com o `jar` do driver e outro arquivo de textos para esconder as credenciais de acesso do código-fonte.

O primeiro arquivo pode ser baixado [aqui](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-ucp-122-downloads.html). Digamos que o segundo arquivo se chamasse `config.oracle`. Seu conteúdo é similar a esse:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//{dns.do.servidor.br}:1521/nome.do.serviço.br
NOME_DO_USUARIO
SENHA_DO_USUARIO
```

E então você pode usar esses arquivos para criar a conexão com

```
driver <- RJDBC::JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "ojdbc8.jar")
configs <- readLines('config.oracle')
conexao <- RJDBC::dbConnect(driver, configs[1], configs[2], configs[3])
```

E depois basta usar o objeto `conexao` par fazer a *query* no banco:

```
tabela <- RJDBC::dbGetQuery(conexao, "SELECT * FROM TABELA")
```

### Edição

Segue abaixo como deve se parecer o objeto do `driver`

```
driver <- RJDBC::JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", "ojdbc8.jar")
class(driver)
[1] "JDBCDriver"
attr(,"package")
[1] "RJDBC"

str(driver)
Formal class 'JDBCDriver' [package "RJDBC"] with 2 slots
  ..@ identifier.quote: chr NA
  ..@ jdrv            :Formal class 'jobjRef' [package "rJava"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ jobj  :<externalptr> 
  .. .. ..@ jclass: chr "oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver"
```

Comment: Olá Tomás Barcellos muito obrigado pela resposta. Eu estou tendo dificuldade no campo 'driver', quando tento executá-lo ele me mostra um erro que diz que a classe não foi encontrada: "Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Comment: Você baixou o arquivo para a mesma pasta do projeto?

Comment: Olá Tomás, enquanto eu aguardava sua resposta, eu consegui encontrar o erro. Já testei e está funcionando perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!